# Extract slopes for all fitted quantile regression models with different tau-values, R

Tags: r, quantiles, quantile-regression

I wonder how I can get the slopes of all the models that were fitted when I do the following:

```
library(quantreq)
z =rq(mpg ~ wt, data=mtcars, tau=-1)
```

Putting the `-1` as the argument for tau, gives you all the quantile regression solutions as I understand. Plotting `z` comes with the following plots:

[image]

Now I wonder how I can extract the slopes (the right plot) for all the quantile regression solutions. The values for `tau` I can access like this:

```
x = z$rho$tau
```

Comment: This is off-topic because it is about programming. See `z$sol`.

Comment: Thanks:) I did not know that